# Airflow execute task in sequence without defining dependency

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

When multiple 'KubernetesPodOperator' tasks are defined in an Airflow DAG, all the tasks gets executed in parallel.

In order to achieve sequential execution, dependencies can be defined, say `task1 >> task2 >> task3` etc.

Problem with this approach is on failure scenario, `task1` alone can't be re-executed, dependency tasks will get executed on `task1` completion.

How to execute tasks in sequence without a dependency? I don't want to modify Airflow config, settings specific to an Airflow DAG/Task is required. Hope that is supported.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "task1 alone can't be re-executed, dependency tasks will get executed on task1 completion"? If task 1 succeeds, then task 2 will be run. If task 1 fails, then task 2 & task 3 will be marked "upstream failed" and will not run. What behaviour are you wanting?

Comment: Actually there is no dependency on the tasks. Ask is to run the task in sequence. When dependency is added, rerun of a successful task (for some reason) triggers downstream tasks, which is not desired.

Comment: How are you re-triggering task 1, through the UI? When you change the status of a task you can [specify if the downstream tasks](https://resources.unizin.org/download/attachments/32833731/Screen%20Shot%202021-05-10%20at%2010.17.52%20AM.png) should be cleared as well.

Comment: @DanielT Yes! This would solve the issue. I can accept this as an answer, please post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential execution needs dependencies definition, but if you want to limit the number of running tasks in your dag, and run only a task at once regardless the order of execution, you can set the dag `concurrency` argument to 1, or use a pool of size 1 in all the dag tasks, but in the two options, you will have a single task running on all the runs.

If your problem with dependencies is just the need to clear a task state without/with clearing the state of the downstream, you can use the UI clear with/without this option:

- Downstream: Clears any tasks in the current DAG run which are downstream from the selected task instance. ([doc](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/rerunning-dags#rerun-tasks))